# stop click action from mousedown event

Tags: php, html, ajax, angularjs, pjax

Im building an application which is intended for speed, and Im thinking to process actual page loads on mousedown event than click event, so the gap between the mousedown and click saves me some milliseconds(about 100ms), my app can load pages with in that 100ms time, so it just runs instant.

```
 $(document).on('mousedown','a.magic_links',function(e) {
             $(this).click().off("click");

            });
```

I tried this code, but not preventing the default click action, any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: could you add more code..so that picture would be clearer..

Comment: thats all the code for this function.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prevent the default behavior of the event (or cancel it).

What you are currently trying to do is remove an event handler that was never created in the first place

```
$(document).on('mousedown','a.magic_links',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // code here to do your loading

});
```

Personally I think you should rethink this over-optimization strategy as it may not be optimal for all devices